# How to handle when some special UTF-8 characters are inside a XML file in matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, parsing, encoding, utf-8

I have several xml files to process. sample file is given below

```
  <DOC>
  <DOCNO>2431.eng</DOCNO>
  <TITLE>The Hot Springs of Baños del Inca near Cajamarca</TITLE>
  <DESCRIPTION>view of several pools with steaming water; people, houses and 
   trees behind it, and a mountain range in the distant background;</DESCRIPTION>
   <NOTES>Until 1532 the place was called Pulltumarca, before it was renamed to
   "Baños  del Inca" (baths of the Inka) with the arrival of the Spaniards . 
   Today, Baños del Inca is the most-visited therapeutic bath of Peru.</NOTES>
   <LOCATION>Cajamarca, Peru</LOCATION>
   </DOC>
```

While using the xmlread() matlab function I get the following error.

```
    [Fatal Error] 2431.eng:3:29: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    ??? Java exception occurred:
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)

    Error in ==> xmlread at 98
    parseResult = p.parse(fileName);
```

Any suggestions of how to get around this problem?

Comment: sorry, the file 2431.eng has the same error. There are many files of this kind.

Comment: check line 3 column 29 of the file `2431.eng`, maybe open it in a HEX editor. Are you sure the files are UTF-8 encoded, not some other encoding?

Comment: Do you mean if the file has this line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>"?  If so, it not mentioned in the file.

Comment: hmm, if the file does not contain sensitive information could you upload it somewhere online (say Dropbox), or at least a redacted version of it? It will make it easier for us to help you solve the problem..

Comment: check the sample file here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zro0dmcojyg2zo/2431.eng)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you posted works just fine.

As the error message says, I think your actual files are incorrectly encoded. Remember that not all possible byte sequences are valid UTF-8 sequences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences

A quick way to check is to open the file in Firefox. If the XML file has encoding problems, you'll see an error message like:

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

---

## EDIT:

So I took a look at the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zro0dmcojyg2zo/2431.eng): Your problem is that XML parsers treat files without the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration line as UTF-8, but your file looks to be encoded as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (Latin 1) or [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (CP-1252) instead.

For instance, the SAX parser choked on the following token: `Baños`. This character "n letter with tilde", which is [U+00F1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm), has different representation in the two encoding:

- in ISO-8859-1, it is represented as one byte:  0xF1
- in UTF-8, it is represented as two bytes: 0xC3 0xB1

While [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) was designed to be backward compatibility with [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the character `ñ` falls into the extended ASCII range, which are all represented as two or more bytes in UTF-8.

So when the substring `ño` stored in Latin-1 as `11110001 01101111` is interpreted as being UTF-8 encoded, the parser sees the first byte and [recognizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) it as the beginning of a 4-byte UTF-8 sequence of the form `11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`. But since it clearly does not follow that format, an error is thrown:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Bottom line is: [Always use an XML declaration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipdecl/index.html)! In your case, add the following line at the beginning of all your files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

or better yet, modify the program that generates these files to write the said line.

After this change, MATLAB (or really Java) should be able read the XML file correctly:

```
>> doc = xmlread('2431.eng');
>> doc.saveXML([])
ans =
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>annotations/02/2431.eng</DOCNO>
<TITLE>The Hot Springs of Baños del Inca near Cajamarca</TITLE>
<DESCRIPTION>view of several pools with steaming water; people, houses and trees behind it, and a mountain range in the distant background;</DESCRIPTION>
<NOTES>Until 1532 the place was called Pulltumarca, before it was renamed to "Baños del Inca" (baths of the Inka) with the arrival of the Spaniards . Today, Baños del Inca is the most-visited therapeutic bath of Peru.</NOTES>
<LOCATION>Cajamarca, Peru</LOCATION>
<DATE>October 2002</DATE>
<IMAGE>images/02/2431.jpg</IMAGE>
<THUMBNAIL>thumbnails/02/2431.jpg</THUMBNAIL>
</DOC>
```

*(Note: Apparently once MATLAB reads the file, it internally re-encodes it as UTF-16)*

Comment: Is there a way to force the parser to parse it without error, even if there are invalid byte sequences?

Comment: I have not seen any "XML Parsing Error" while I opened the file in firefox.

Comment: @vidyadhar: problem solved, see my edit. fwiw, Firefox does complain that the file is not well-formed :)