# nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, spring, utf-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:hsf="http://www.taobao.com/hsf"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.taobao.com/hsf http://www.taobao.com/hsf/hsf.xsd">

    <hsf:consumer id="fcAccountQueryService"
        interface="com.aliexpress.finance.open.fcaccount.share.service.FcAccountQueryService"
        version="1.0.0" group="DUBBO" />
</beans>
```

This is my xml file, but when I deploy, I got error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [biz/consumer/services/spring_fc_account_services.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.`. Why?

And the other xml line 6 is

```
<beans>
    <import resource="/consumer/services/spring_fc_account_services.xml" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Did you google the error message?

Comment: @hagello Yes, it tell me that the xml file's encoding is error, but I'm sure it's correct.

Comment: How did you check? I would use a _recode_ or _iconv_.

Comment: @hagello I got the answer, i miss the ```hsf``` dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: What's hsf? I'm not convinced that resolved the actual issue

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack it's true, when i add the hsf dependency to my pom.xml, all problems resolved. hsf is a java remote service invocation framework, developed by alibaba.

Comment: And if you remove the dependency, does it fail again? (I'm trying to make sure this question has benefit to others)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Yes, I'm sure. Because I try it in other spring application, it's also occured.

Comment: Ok, cool. Can you add your resolution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to save file in `UTF-8` format and in `ISO-8859-1`, I get the error again. So it's not caused by encoding.
And I try to add the same xml file to other spring application, it works. I'm sure all the xml files are same.
Then I compared the two app's dependency. I found the app which worked well has a dependency of `hsf`.
In my xml file, I used `http://www.taobao.com/hsf http://www.taobao.com/hsf/hsf.xsd` xsd. So I add the `hsf` dependency to my pom.xml, all problems was solved, the app started successful!

Answer (score 0):

> This means that the xml file is saved in some other format other than
>   `UTF-8`

Try saving file in `UTF-8` format

Try referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452421/how-to-handle-when-some-special-utf-8-characters-are-inside-a-xml-file-in-matlab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545720/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence) for similar problem

Answer (score 0):

There Might be some Special Characters which you are not able to see because the editor,terminal,gedit tools etc doesn't support that character.

Another way to handle the same exception what I found is

```
new String(bytes,"ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-16");
```

If your contents are giving the SAXException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.